# Accessing Cleaned Data of one form inside a second form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I have two forms, Sale and SaleItems

```
SaleForm = SaleForm(request.POST or None, auto_id=False, prefix = 'SaleForm')
SaleItemsForm = modelformset_factory(
        Sale, form = SaleItemsForm, formset = ItemsFormSet, extra=1, can_delete=True
)
```

once they're both given POST data and valid, they're in the usual statement:

```
if SaleForm.is_valid() and SaleItemsForm.is_valid():
    pass
```

When it comes time to do validation I've superseded the basemodelformset and want to write my own custom clean method for the modelformset.  I want to use cleaned data from SaleForm inside the clean method for the ItemsFormSet:

```
from django import forms

class ItemsFormSet(forms.models.BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemsFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        print(TheSaleForm.cleaned_data['Value'])
```

This doesn't work, and I've tried a few dumb things:

- try to make SaleForm a global and access it between the views.py and forms.py modules.  That was a bad idea and now I understand more about the module scope
- try to import the actual object, again not smart

I'm assuming there has to be a way to do this without saving the cleaned data off somewhere to the database and retrieving it again in the clean method of the formset.  I'm not sure if overwriting `ItemsFormSet.is_valid()` and trying to allow a kwarg dictionary item to be passed through would be the right way to go.... but I'm hoping someone has an idea of what the "correct" way to approach this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow the data to be passed into the init of ItemsFormSet and keep it as an instance attribute which you can reference later.

```
class ItemsFormSet(forms.models.BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sale_form = kwargs.pop('sale_form', None)
        super(ItemsFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        print(self.sale_form.cleaned_data['Value'])
```

and now in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SaleForm(request.POST)
    formset = SaleItemsForm(request.POST, sale_form=form)
```

Comment: Ah, I definitely wasn't thinking about the idea that the `SaleForm` itself could be kept as an instance to be referenced, I actually have been passing other variables into some of the forms this way, but didn't think I could do it without the form already being "finished" for the cleaned_data.

Thank You!